# Adding uiTextView before uiScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I want the textview to be before the scrollview inside my tablecell like this, so that the scrollview scrolls and the titles stays put.

```
[Title goes here] - it does not move with the scrollview
---------------------
|                   |
|    ScrollView     |
|                   |
---------------------
```

**This is my code, the textView appears behind the scrollview.**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    NSInteger numberOfViews = 10;
    UIScrollView *vwScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1280, 200)];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
        CGFloat xOrigin = i * 250;
        UITextView *titleView = [[UITextView alloc]  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1280, 20)];
        titleView.text = @"Title";
        [titleView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaBold" size:32]];


        UIView *awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, 250, 180)];
        awesomeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5/i green:0.5/i/10 blue:0.5 alpha:1];
        [awesomeView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
        [awesomeView.layer setBorderWidth:10.5f];
        awesomeView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:awesomeView.bounds].CGPath;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:titleView];
        [vwScroll addSubview:awesomeView];

    }
    vwScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(250 * numberOfViews, 200);

    [cell.contentView addSubview:vwScroll];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why cant you just set the frame of your titleView to, say, `(0,0,width,titleHeight)` and then set the frame of your scrollView to `(0,titleHeight,width,cellHeight-titleHeight)`.

This will just place the title at the top part of the cell, setting it's height to whatever you make `titleHeight` to be, and will put the scrollView at the bottom part of the cell, setting it's height to the rest of the cell.

Comment: did you set the scrollView's Y coordinate to be the same as teh textView's height?

Comment: ah thats the problem! Man, i did not think about that, thanks, add that to your answer and Ill give you a green mark :-)

Comment: it is in the answer :) in the second coordinate of the scrollView's frame is `titleHeight`.